# Deshabilitar NavLink en Blazor

Tags: html, c#, razor, blazor

Estoy intentando **deshabilitar un NavLink** como este:

```
<NavLink class="nav-link" href="NovaDedicacio" >
    <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Imputar dedicació propia
</NavLink>
```

Pero el control no me ofrece la opción Enable/Disable/IsDisabled/... ni nada parececido.
[image: Opciones que ofrece el control NavLink]

Debo usar el NavLink si o si. ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de como puedo hacerlo?

Muchas gracias

Enlaces relacionados con el control:
https://blazor-university.com/routing/navigating-our-app-via-html/

Comment: ¿Por que no usas css? puedes hacerlo con blazor, con una etiqueta html o añadiendo una clase directamente

Comment: @NicolasOñate Lo he pensado, pero ¿Se podrá seguir clicando no? Necesito que se inhabilite totalmente sin que desaparezca

Comment: tal vez con [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled) puedas lograrlo

Answer (score 1):

NavLink es un componente y no tiene propiedad "disabled" pero siendo un componente lo que hace es recoger todos los atributos adicionales que desconoce y luego los coloca en el tag.

El codigo fuente de esta clase/componente podeis encontrar en el siguiente enlace oficial en github:

[NavLink.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a28da74c363454b78fbcf042e1a94dfc6e255e1a/src/Components/Web/src/Routing/NavLink.cs)

Como podeis observar en la linea 35 y 36:

```
    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>? AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }
```

Tenemos la recogida de todos los atirbutos adicionales (Unmatched) los que se añaden al componente en el momento de renderización en la fila 166:

```
builder.AddMultipleAttributes(1, AdditionalAttributes);
```

Con esta esta captura de atributos podemos utilizar el atributo "disabled='true'" como si fuera un control HTML normal. Despues en CSS podeis crear estilos especiales a los NavLink que tengan este atributo con valor "true" y "false".

Answer (score -1):

Nicolas Oñate me dió la solución. Añadí este style a mi conjunto de css:

```
.isDisabled {
  color: currentColor;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Y lo añadí a mi NavLink:

```
<NavLink class="nav-link isDisabled" href="NovaDedicacio" >
```

Muchas gracias Nicolas, espero que mi respuesta pueda ayudar a alguien.